# How to extract sqlite file

Tags: data-recovery, file-management, sqlite, media-files

My *Samsung Galaxy S* was having an error on the notification bar saying `sd card blank or has unsupported file system`, so I was required to format my sd card. However, I couldn't format it using the phone, and my lappy couldnt recognize it either. So I formatted the card using my *Nokia 5800*, and it works.

I tried to recover lost images and songs using [Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). However, I was only able to recover 3 files and all of them are sqlite files. One of them is 2gb in size which match the size of all the photos and songs that I used to have. Is the sqlite file my lost data or not? If it is, how can I convert it back to photos and songs that I mentioned earlier?

Comment: You're trying to view an SQLite file on your computer?  You should perhaps ask on Super User, though I would Google first -- we only handle Android-specific PC questions, like drivers and the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

That's odd, photos are usually stored within a `DCIM` directory of the SD-Card. Never heard that one would store them as binary blob within a sqlite db.

Anyways, you cold discover the contents of the sqlite db with the `sqlite` (sometimes `sqlite3`) tool. But you need some [basic understanding](http://sqlite.org/quickstart.html) of [SQL syntax](http://sqlite.org/lang.html).